# Wildfly how to use deployment's classes from custom module

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, wildfly-10

I'm using undertow subsystem and created a module for my custom filter.

Registered module as:

```
module add --name=example.com.handler --resources=/home/owner/module/jbossModule.jar
```

Added filter in standalone.xml

```xml
<filter name="my-filter" module="example.com.handler" class-name="example.com.handler.ExampleHandler"/>
```

I have deployed my war with `TestClass`.

In my custom filter `ExampleHandler.java`, I'm reading class name from an external config, and using `Class.forName(...)` to create new instance.

To simplify:

```java
public class ExampleHandler implements HttpHandler {


    public ExampleHandler () {
    }

    @Override
    public void handleRequest(HttpServerExchange exchange) throws Exception {
          final String className = "TestClass"
          Class.forName(className).newInstance();
    }
}
```

But inside `ExampleHandler`, class `TestClass` is not found and ClassNotFoundException is raised.

How can I make a module to be able to access classes from deployments?

Answer (score 0):

To make TestClass.class visible to war file you have to add module dependency on war file through jboss-deployment-structure.xml file. jboss-deployment-structure.xml will look like as for war file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
<deployment>
     <dependencies>  
          <module name="example.com.handler" />       
    </dependencies>  

 </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Place this file under WEB-INF directory. Go through [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Class+Loading+in+AS7) for more details about wildfly classloading.

Comment: Sorry, maybe it's not obvious from my question, but i need exactly the opposite. TestClass is inside my .war. I need to use it from custom module

Comment: classes from war and module are in different classloader. And there is no way we can access  class available in war from module.

Comment: You could extract the common class inside a second module and have both the first module and the .war depend on this second module.

Answer (score 0):

It appears Wildfly puts the deployment's classLoader in thread contextClassLoader.

Sure it's more a hack than an elegant solution. But in case you don't have any options:

```
final String className = "TestClass"
Class.forName(className, true, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader())
```